# search through a array and create a new array with the result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to search through an array and want to return the result like the example provided below.

I know I could just loop through the array, but I want to see if there is a better way to do this, as this will be searching through a large set of data.

Search through an array like this:

```
// initial array
$search_thru = array(
    array('member_id' => 6, 'field_id_1' => 'some data', 'field_id_5' => NULL),
    array('member_id' => 15, 'field_id_1' => NULL, 'field_id_5' => NULL),
    array('member_id' => 21, 'field_id_1' => 'this field too', 'field_id_5' => 'this field has some data');
);
```

Search through the array, if the `member_id` has any keys equal to NULL, then add it to the result array.

The `member_id` should be the key of the dataset in the new array.
The data to the key should not be the full names of the key where the value was NULL, just the number.

Example: `field_id_1 => 1`.

```
// expected result
$result = array(
    6 => array(5),
    15 => array(1, 5),
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Foreach loops are very easy to write. You can heavily customize them for your personal needs. The runtime is O(n). So, I don't see a reason you shouldn't hit each index in a foreach loop and append to your result array as you go.

Comment: [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) would seem a logical starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do parts of this in a functional style, but PHP's `array_map` doesn't let you work with array keys, so `foreach` seems like the most straightforward way to output the format you need:

```
<?php

function strip_prefix( $string ) {
  $prefix = 'field_id_';
  return explode( $prefix, $string )[1];
}

function get_null_fields( $member ) {
  $null_keys = array_keys( $member, NULL, true ); // get all keys with NULL values
  return array_map( 'strip_prefix', $null_keys );
}

// initial array
$search_thru = array(
    array('member_id' => 6,  'field_id_1' => 'some data', 'field_id_5' => NULL),
    array('member_id' => 15, 'field_id_1' => NULL, 'field_id_5' => NULL),
    array('member_id' => 21, 'field_id_1' => 'this field too', 'field_id_5' => 'this field has some data')
);

$tmp = array();
foreach ( $search_thru as $member ) {
  $tmp[ $member['member_id'] ] = get_null_fields($member);
}

$result = array_filter( $tmp, 'count' ); // remove items with no null fields

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are better functions for array manipulation, when key changes are needed, the `foreach` loops seems to be the easy approach:

```
<?php

$haystack = array(
  array('member_id' => 6, 'field_id_1' => 'some data', 'field_id_5' => NULL),
  array('member_id' => 15, 'field_id_1' => NULL, 'field_id_5' => NULL),
  array('member_id' => 21, 'field_id_1' => 'this field too', 'field_id_5' => 'this field has some data'),
);

$result = array();
foreach($haystack as $row) {
  if(in_array(null, $row)) {
    $result[$row['member_id']] = array();

    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
      if($value === null) {
        $result[$row['member_id']][] = str_replace('field_id_', '', $key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think there is [array_search()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp) and [in_array()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) at your disposal.

Actually you can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) Should be the correct function.
It should return all the keys that match the value then you can easily loop through the keys to perform whatever manipulations you need.

Though this approach is may not be more efficient than just looping through the whole dataset if you have many null values.